# Manage friendly enum with XAML MarkupExtension

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I start from this:
[bitwise flag enum](http://dotnet-journey.blogspot.it/2010/09/c-bitwise-flag-enum.html)
and this:
[accessing enum members](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/accessing-enum-members-in-xaml/)

this is my code

```
[Flags]
public enum DeliveryDays
{
    [Description("None")]
    NONE = 0, // 0000000

    [Description("monday")]
    MON = 1,  // 0000001

    [Description("tuersady")]
    TUE = 2,  // 0000010

    [Description("wedsnay")]
    WED = 4,  // 0000100

    [Description("thursday")]
    THU = 8,  // 0001000

    [Description("friday")]
    FRI = 16, // 0010000

    [Description("saturday")]
    SAT = 32, // 0100000

    [Description("sunday")]
    SUN = 64, // 1000000

    WORKDAYS = MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI,  //0011111
    WEEKENDS = SAT | SUN  //1100000
} 

public class Finder 
{
    public DeliveryDays AvailableDays = DeliveryDays.WEEKENDS;

    public DeliveryDays SelectedDays { get; set; }

    public Finder()
    {
        SelectedDays = DeliveryDays.NONE;
    }    
}
```

and this is XAML

```
<ComboBox Height="50"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={my:Enumeration {x:Type my:DeliveryDays}}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Description"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDays}"
          SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

Now the combobox show me all enum in `DeliveryDays` type, but I want only then enum values in the `AvailableDays` instance member field. So I need to modify the custom `MarkupExtension` to show only the enums value in my `AvailableDays` field. How can I access to this field from my custom `EnumListExtension` method? If is not possibile in XAML have you any workaround?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a pure XAML solution, but this works:

I tested it on `UriKind` enum (for speed). I think it's easier just to see the whole solution.

This is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:sysSys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
        xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="UriKindProvider"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                            MethodName="GetValues">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type Type="sysSys:UriKind" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="EnumCollection"
                              Source="{StaticResource UriKindProvider}"
                              Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumCollection}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the code-behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            var valueToCompare = (UriKind)e.Item;
            e.Accepted = IsInAvailableDays(valueToCompare);
        }

        private bool IsInAvailableDays(UriKind value)
        {
            //this is for testing only, replace with actual logic to compare to AvailableDays
            if (value.ToString().Contains("Abs"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this you will see a combo with only the values "RelativeOrAbsolute" and "Absolute" ("Relative" is filtered out).